# Iterate through multidimensional arraylist to hashMap in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a table as follows

```
                     Total  Upright  Supine  Meal  PostPr  ChestP     Other
Duration of Period   22:38  14:30   08:08  01:02   06:54   00:48     00:28
Number of Refluxes    5       4       1      0       3       2         0
```

From this I have created a multidimensional array `Arr_ReflDay1_table2d` as follows:

```
 [[Total, Upright, Supine, Meal, PostPr, ChestP, Other], [Duration of Period , 22:38, 14:30, 08:08, 01:02, 06:54, 00:48, 00:28], [Number of Refluxes, 5, 4, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0]]
```

I want to get it into a HashMap such that the Key is the row and column name a value came from. For example the hashMap might read:

`Total_DurationOfPeriod=22:38,Upright_DurationOfPeriod=14:30,Supine_DurationOfPeriod=08:08` etc.

I tried doing this:

```
Map<String,String> mapReflDay1= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    ArrayList<List<String>> Arr_ReflDay1_table2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        for (int ff=0;ff<Arr_ReflDay1_table2d.size();ff++){
               for (int fg=0;fg<Arr_ReflDay1_table2d.size();fg++){
                  for (int fx=0;fx<Arr_ReflDay1_table2d.get(0).size();fx++){
                            mapReflDay1.put("ReflDay1"+Arr_ReflDay1_table2d.get(0).get(ff)+Arr_ReflDay1_table2d.get(fg).get(0)+","Arr_ReflDay1_table2d.get(ff).get(fx));
        }
                }
                      }
```

which gives the key fine but the value seems to only be taken from the final column

Comment: Why don't you use classes and objects, with actual types instead of Strings? Everything would be so much clearer and safer. I see a class Analysis with two fields (duration, of type Duration, and refluxCount, of type int), and 7 variables of type Analysis, named total, upright, etc. don't use Strings, arrays and maps to model everything. Java is an OO, strongly-typed language. Use proper types, and define classes.

Comment: I was just showing the MCVE. The ArrayList is typed. I've added it and got rid of the strings.

Comment: Solved it in the end. Just added an extra element to the first inner ArrayList so I was iterating over the same number of elements in each inner ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Solved it in the end. Just added an extra element to the first inner ArrayList so I was iterating over the same number of elements in each inner ArrayList